# mysql UNION ALL, ORDER BY, LIMIT and INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables as below

```
T1:
+------------+---------------+  
|  Username  |  Role         |  
+------------+---------------+  
|    User1   |  System Admin |  
|    User2   |  Group Admin  |  
|    User3   |  Admin HR     |  
+------------+---------------+
```

```
T2:
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+-------+  
| Id | Username |       IP       | Authentication | Type  |
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+-------+ 
| 1  | User1    | 10.110.150.111 | Success        | Type1 | 
| 2  | User2    | 10.110.150.121 | Failure        | Type2 |
| 3  | User3    | 10.109.110.110 | Failure        | Type2 |  
| 4  | User1    | 10.110.150.111 | Success        | Type2 |  
| 5  | User1    | 10.110.150.109 | Success        | Type2 |  
| 6  | User4    | 10.25.109.110  | Failure        | Type2 |  
| 7  | NULL     | 10.29.109.110  | Failure        | Type1 |  
| 8  | NULL     | 10.29.209.110  | Failure        | Type2 |  
| 9  | User2    | 10.110.151.116 | Failure        | Type1 |  
| 10 | User2    | 10.110.150.121 | Success        | Type2 |  
| 11 | User5    | 10.105.105.111 | Failure        | Type2 |
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+-------+
```

In Table T2, there could be more no records per User. I'm trying to fetch the records from T2 based on the Usernames in T1, and each user which matches users in T1, should fetch 5 `Type1` and 5 `Type2` records. Along with these should fetch those records whose username is blank/NULL.

The expected output is as below:

```
+----------+----------------+----------------+-------+  
+ Username |       IP       | Authentication | Type  |
+----------+----------------+----------------+-------+ 
| User1    | 10.110.150.111 | Success        | Type1 |  
| User1    | 10.110.150.111 | Success        | Type2 | 
| User1    | 10.110.150.109 | Success        | Type2 |  
| User2    | 10.110.150.121 | Failure        | Type2 |
| User2    | 10.110.151.116 | Failure        | Type1 |  
| User2    | 10.110.150.121 | Success        | Type2 |
| User3    | 10.109.110.110 | Failure        | Type2 |  
| NULL     | 10.29.109.110  | Failure        | Type1 |  
| NULL     | 10.29.209.110  | Failure        | Type2 | 
+----------+----------------+----------------+-------+
```

Tried with the below query:

```
 (SELECT T3.USERNAME, IP, AUTHENTICATION, TYPE 
    FROM ((SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE TYPE = 'Type1' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5)  
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE TYPE = 'Type2' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5)) T3
    INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.LOGINNAME = T1.LOGINNAME) 
  UNION ALL
 (SELECT T2.USERNAME, IP, AUTHENTICATION, TYPE FROM T2 WHERE T2.USERNAME IS NULL);
```

But not getting the expected records. Please suggest on the changes to be done.

Comment: This is complicated in MySQL, because it both lags standard SQL's `ROW_NUMBER` and `CROSS APPLY`. Either of these would easily solve this. Your best bet will be to look up how to mimic `ROW_NUMBER` with variables in MySQL to get n records per group, because you want 5 records per username and type.

Comment: Well, it's not that complicated, but see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You have column name for user USERNAME and not LOGINNAME and you are referring to table T3 after the inner UNION ALL (and not t2)

```
(SELECT T3.USERNAME, T3.IP, T3.AUTHENTICATION, T3TYPE 
    FROM (
        SELECT T2.USERNAME, T2.IP, T2.AUTHENTICATION, T2.TYPE  
        FROM T2 WHERE TYPE = 'Type1' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT T2.USERNAME, T2.IP, T2.AUTHENTICATION, T2.TYPE  
        FROM T2 WHERE TYPE = 'Type2' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5 ) T3
    INNER JOIN T1 ON T3.USERNAME = T1.USERNAME )
UNION ALL
(SELECT T2.USERNAME, T2.IP, T2.AUTHENTICATION, T2.TYPE 
FROM T2 WHERE T2.USERNAME IS NULL)
```

Comment: After doing the suggested changes, I'm getting this ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias.